# minicart-count background does not disappear, even no items in cart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, magento2.0.8

1. Add items into cart

[image]

2. Delete browser **cache** and **cookies** only [CTRL + SHIFT + DLETE]
3. Load the page again, it shows no count but cart-count background
   does not disappear

[image]

How to debug what is the root causes of the problem?

---

### update

as per this line in `Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml` (take this from firebug)

```
<span data-bind="css: { empty: cart().summary_count == 0 }, blockLoader: isLoading" class="counter qty">
```

**empty** class added when cart count is zero, but it is never add empty class for the above scenario

If I remove item from minicart window instead of browser, it works and empty class also added.

Answer (score 1):

### Debug Magento Mini Cart

If we want to debug the Js Mini Cart, you find the js - `minicart.js`, for example: `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart.js`.

#### Using Chrome to debug

We can debug with Chrome.

[image]

### Try with the latest Magento version

I checked with Magento 2.1.1 version, seem they fixed this problem.
The new function `getCartParam('summary_count')` will be used.

```
data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is css, you are missing a standard part of the magento.css

```
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart .counter.qty.empty {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: no! this is not an answer. I thought, when cart is empty above css automatically get call. we don't need to force anything. I have this problem in staging system only, In development system it works. If you need any further details, please feel free to mention in comment.

Comment: are you saying the empty class is not being added?

Comment: review my updated question